# Excluding bad sectors from list when formatting

Tags: badblocks, mkfs

I am preparing a old HDD for use with my Pi. But it has >36 bad sectors (avoce threshold). So I ran `badblocks` to investigate which sectors are affected and saved them to a file.

The file now contains basically a list of all affected sectors separated by linebreaks.

How can I use this information now with `mkfs.ext4` so it won't allocate data blocks at those addresses?

Comment: `man mkfs.ext4` tells you how to do this (look at the `-cc` and `-l` options. Which bit is unclear?

Comment: Also, unless it's a *really* old HDD, writing zeroes to the bad blocks with `dd` will cause them to be remapped by the HDD, which is better then bad block management by the filesystem. Have a look at `smartctl` to get info about reallocated blocks etc.

Comment: Hello, the HDD has only bad sectors in the same spot, it a really old hdd and I only save big dumps and stuff on it where the integrity is not that important to me.

Answer (score 1):

So I made a mistake:
I searched the hard disk for bad sectors using the badblocks command instead of using mkfs.ext4 with the -c option in the first place.

The only problem is I do not want to repeat the search because it took like 2 days time.

I ran the command pointing to the descriptor file sda so I think the information I have now is sectors (LBA adresses).

So I could just calculate and create two partitions because the sectors are pretty much in the same spot.

- But it would be better to create one single partition with no split.
  -- *Is anyone so sly* and knows in what format the command wants the information for example if I create a partition with 4K block size. If anyone helps me with that that would be awesome!

Some questions:

- In wich way are partition-start-address and partition-block-size relevant in converting the information?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself now.
By default an block size of 1k (1024) is used when pointing to a device like /dev/sda rather than a partition.

And when you run mke2fs pointing to a device rather than a partition (w/ start adress and end adress) then no MBR is written / MBR is overwritten.

$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00240179 s, 213 kB/s
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200

So you just have to divide the adresses with 4 and keep in mind one 4k block has 4 1k blocks to calculate the adresses.
Then you can create a file and run mke2fs with the newly created file to isolate the bad blocks. Like this:
mke2fs -f ext4 -l badblocks_file /dev/sdX